# APL: Matrix manipulation trick?

Tags: matrix, apl

I'm trying to find a way (idiomatic or otherwise) to transform a matrix that looks like

```
0 1
0 1
0 1
```

into 3 individual matrices

```
0 1
0 0
0 0

0 0
0 1
0 0

0 0
0 0
0 1
```

so that when I OR all of them together, I get the original.
Each of these "sub-matrices" have to have 1 non-zero element only and must have the same shape as the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution:

Any boolean matrix:

```
      m←4 3⍴?12⍴2
      m
0 0 1
0 0 0
1 1 0
0 1 0
```

Note its shape:

```
    d←⍴m
    d
4 3
```

Ravel the matrix into a vector:

```
      v←,m
      v
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
```

Generate indices:

```
          i ←⍳⍴v
          i
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

Construct a matrix for each 1 in the original matrix:

```
      a←d∘⍴¨↓(v/i)∘.=i
      a
 0 0 1  0 0 0  0 0 0  0 0 0 
 0 0 0  0 0 0  0 0 0  0 0 0 
 0 0 0  1 0 0  0 1 0  0 0 0 
 0 0 0  0 0 0  0 0 0  0 1 0
```

Verify result:

```
   ↑∨/a
0 0 1
0 0 0
1 1 0
0 1 0
```

There is probably a nice way to do this using scatter point indexing as well, by first generating a 3 dimensional matrix and then specifying the location of the 1s.

Yes there is, using v and d as above:

```
       n←+/v
       b←(n,d)⍴0
       b[↓⍉(⍳n)⍪d⊤v/⍳⍴v]←1
       b
0 0 1
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

0 0 0
0 0 0
1 0 0
0 0 0

0 0 0
0 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 0

0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 1 0
      ∨⌿b
0 0 1
0 0 0
1 1 0
0 1 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Given a vector A:

```
+A←3 4⍴1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1

1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 1
```

Break it down into component matrices as follows:

```
+(⍴A)∘⍴¨⊂[2](,A)\B B⍴1,(B←+/,A)⍴0

1 0 0 0   0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   1 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   0 1 0 0   0 0 0 1
```

**How it works**

First assign the number of 1s to B:

```
B←+/,A          ⍝ 5
```

Create an identity matrix as discussed in this post: [The most idiomatic way of creating identity matrix in APL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385783/the-most-idiomatic-way-of-creating-identity-matrix-in-apl):

```
B B⍴1,(B←+/,A)⍴0

1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1
```

Ravel the original matrix:

```
,A              ⍝ 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
```

Use the raveled matrix to expand the identity matrix. That creates a matrix wherein each row is the raveled form of the component matrices:

```
+(,A)\B B⍴1,(B←+/,A)⍴0

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Convert that matrix into a vector of the rows:

```
+⊂[2](,A)\B B⍴1,(B←+/,A)⍴0

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Using the original shape of A `(⍴A)`, create the final matrices:

```
(⍴A)∘⍴¨⊂[2](,A)\B B⍴1,(B←+/,A)⍴0

1 0 0 0   0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   1 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   0 1 0 0   0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Very nice solution! I like this one because it is just reshaping the 1's and 0's, and aside from the count of the number of 1's needs no integers or indices. I had thought there must be some way to do it this way and toyed with expansion, but generating the identity matrix did not occur to me. Very nice indeed!

Comment: @PaulMansour - Thanks, Paul! I liked your solution too, but I'm little stumped by it because I'm getting a valence error with `↓(v/i)∘.=i`. Shouldn't there be an argument to the left of that?

Comment: Monadic down arrow is known as "split" and does the same thing as ⊂[2], converting a matrix into a vector of vectors. May not be available in all APL implementions.

Comment: @PaulMansour - That's probably the case since I'm using NARS2000. I'll try it with `⊂[2]`. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

With *Dyalog APL version 16.0* you can now write this very succinctly with the tacit function `⍸{~@(⊂⍺)≠⍨⍵}⍤0 2⊢`. <sup>See the bottom of this post for how to get a list of matrices instead.</sup>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///PzgzLz0ntfhR24RHvTuq6xw0HnU1Perdpfmoc8Gj3hWPerfWPupdYqBg9KhrEVyxgjGQ37vFQMEQAA)

**How does it work?**

It is a fork, where so the results of `⍸` and of `⊢` are the left and right arguments to `{~@(⊂⍺)≠⍨⍵}⍤0 2`.

`⍸` gives a list of **indices where** there are 1s in the argument

`⊢` just **yield**s the unmodified argument

`{`…`}⍤0 2` applies the following dfn with each **rank-0** subarray of the left argument (i.e. each index of a 1) as left argument and each **rank-2** subarray of the right argument (i.e. the entire matrix) as right argument

`≠⍨⍵` **unequal selfie** of the **right argument**; gives a matrix of same shape but filled with zeros

`~@(⊂⍺)` this flips (logical **not**) the bit **at** the position indicated by the **left argument**

So, for each 1, it creates an all-zero layer where the bit in its position is flipped.

---

**How to get a list of matrices instead:**

`⍸{~@(⊂⍺)≠⍨⍵}¨⊂` gives a list of the desired matrices. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///PzgzLz0ntfhR24RHvTuq6xw0HnU1Perdpfmoc8Gj3hWPerfWHloBFIIrVDBWMHrUu8VAwRAA)

This works identically, but instead of using the rank operator to operate on the entire array, we use `¨⊂` to pair each index of a 1 with the entire matrix.